# How to extract blocks of text from a HTML page?

Tags: php, html, html-content-extraction

I would like to extract blocks of texts with more than 100 words from a large HTML page using PHP. Whether the text is contained in `<p>...</p>` doesn't matter. I only care about the number of words that makes a coherent text block so texts outside of HTML paragraphs should also be taken into consideration.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use phpQuery. Are you familiar with jQuery? they share the same syntax. You might be concerned about installing a new library, but trust me this library is well worth the extra over head

## [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

You can then access it like this:

```
foreach($doc->find('p') as $element){
   $element = pq($element);
   echo str_word_count($element->text());
}
```

Comment: What advantage would this give me over PHP Simple DOM Parser? The syntax seems identical.

Comment: You can use the jquery selectors. so you could use p:last-child, or p + a, or p:nth-child(2), etc. Greater selector flexibility is just one of the advantages though, because PHP Query can act like a full server to server browser, by making a request, retrieving the page and performing some manipulations on it.

Comment: @lecodesportif: Simple_HTML_DOM has no facilities for error management, at all. So when you load your document, you have no way of knowing if it did load or not. The rest of the methods are no better. Personally, I would use phpQuery over SHTMLDOM every day.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $element){
   echo str_word_count($element->src);
}
```

Comment: What about text that is not contained in `<p>...</p>`?

Comment: You can cycle over all elements, and pick out those with large blocks of text quite easily.